# How do you say "a runaway" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, word-choice, noun

A policeman found a `runaway`walking along highway 75.

> Ein Polizist hat eine Fliehende auf dem Highway 75 entlang gehen finden.

A lot of suggestions came up for the word "runaway" and I chose only two words that fit the context: *Fliehende* and 'Davonläuferin'.
Which word is appropriate in this context? Furthermore, I am not even sure if *finden* is the right word in this context. I wonder if I can use *auffinden* in this context.

Comment: Fl*ie*hende, bitte!

Comment: actually my dictionary does offer many translations but not those you list: http://dict.leo.org/#/search=runaway&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on - you should definitely consider to consult a different dictionary!

Comment: That's what i used :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the term Ausreißer in this context. The proper translation would then be:

**"Der Polizist fand einen am Highway 75 entlanggehenden Ausreißer (eine entlanggehende Ausreißerin)"**

I am aware of the fact that this is more complicated but in my book this would be a good translation. Easier but still correct:

**"Der Polizist fand am Highway 75 einen Ausreißer (eine Ausreißerin)."**

Hope this helps

Comment: Does that mean  a girl who run away from home? Because `Flüchtige` sounds like the girl escaped from prison.

Comment: I removed the commas and the gender-inclusive shorthand. I'm all for it, but you really should use the long form, especially when addressing learners of German.

Comment: Was ist mit "Entflohene"? Ich kenne "runaway" nicht um sagne zu können, ob das in Betracht kommt. "Flüchtende" wäre auch noch denkbar.

Comment: The verb "finden" seems inappropriate here. "Finden" is like finding a lost purse on the street. Or perhaps policmen would indeed find a suspect, but this needs active search beforehand. In your context, it would be rather "aufgreifen" (a form of 'arresting'): "Der Polizist griff den Ausreißer am Highway 75 auf." This alludes that the encounter was not planned, or the result of a purposeful search, rather accidentially.

Answer (score 7):

`Ausreißerin`: typically a teenager running away from home or an institution

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm, Google translate gives me:

> der Ausreißer    runaway, stray bullet
>
> der Ausbrecher   escapee, jailbreaker, gaolbreaker, runaway
>
> der Flüchtling   refugee, fugitive, runaway

Also possible IMHO:

> der/die Flüchtige

However, we can't use constructs like "entlang gehen finden".
Looks like you want tell too much in one sentence.

> Ein Polizist hat die Flüchtige gefunden, als sie den Highway 75 entlang ging.

Answer (score 0):

I would say

**"Der Polizist fand einen Ausreißer (eine Ausreißerin), der/die am Highway entlang ging.**

or

**"Der Polizist fand einen Ausreißer (eine Ausreißerin) am Highway entlanggehen.**